# ATL Services Project not able to run on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, atl

I have created ATL Services. When I am building it gives message on Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 64 bit PC

```
**1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Performing registration**
```

one wondow pops up with dialogue " **Could not Open Service Manager** "

and When I am trying to run my project its giving this error

```
**First-chance exception at 0x7709c41f in XYZ.exe: 0x00000005: Access is denied.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1844) has exited with code 1063 (0x427).
The program '[10592] XYZ.exe: Native' has exited with code 1063 (0x427).**
```

I checked regedit too, nothing is registered in regedit/Appid.

Someone Please help me to understand this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, that VS is able to modify the registry you must start VS "As Administrator...". by Default the UAC prevents the Access to the registry. So right click VS and select "Run as Administrator..."

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jochen, I tried same thing but same result :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, ATL version of Visual Studio 2005 is not DEP-safe: it executes thunk code from addresses not specifically allowed to contain executable code. This crashes the application, and you need to either fix thunks on ATL code, or put your application on [DEP exception list](http://pclhelp.com/product-installation/data-execution-prevention-dep-in-vista-windows7/).